# Filtering the terms of a specific vocabulary

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

How do I get all the taxonomy terms of a specific vocabulary? If a page has terms coming from 2 vocabularies (e.g. "Software" and "Hardware"), how do I display the terms coming only from the vocabulary "Software," and not from "Hardware"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a view, to filter terms from a page tagged with more than one vocabulary, so that only the terms from, say, `Hardware` show, you would:

- under **Format**, change the default 'Content' format to 'Fields'
- under **Fields**, add a 'Taxonomy: All Terms' field
- scroll down to the 'More' section and click
- you should see a screen like below, which allows you to filter terms to a single vocabulary (or more, if needed)
  http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/9266/filtertoonevocabulary.png